# Is there a way to separate the session states in streamlit app for two bullet options?

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit, llama-index

I have created a streamlit app that has two separate chatbots leveraging llamaindex. For the chatbot the streamlit session code for interaction with the user is common. Due to this, I can see the chats from one chatbot shown in the other when I am switching between the two.

The code for the streamlit is

```
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(verbose=True)

    if "messages" not in st.session_state.keys():  # Initialize the chat messages history
        st.session_state.messages = [
            {"role": "assistant", "content": "Hi, Welcome to KnowledgeGPT"},
            {"role": "assistant", "content": f"Ask me questions from {file_name}"}
        ]

    if prompt := st.chat_input("Your question"):  # Prompt for user input and save to chat history
        st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})

    for message in st.session_state.messages:  # Display the prior chat messages
        with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
            st.write(message["content"])

    # If last message is not from assistant, generate a new response
    if st.session_state.messages[-1]["role"] != "assistant":
        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
            with st.spinner("Thinking..."):
                response = chat_engine.chat(prompt)
                st.write(response.response)
                message = {"role": "assistant", "content": response.response}
                st.session_state.messages.append(message)  # Add response to message history
```

I am expecting that the session states are maintained within the chatbot and not when switching between the two chatbots.

Answer (score 3):

I revisited streamlit sessions and understood. I just had to keep changing the session names from st.session_state.messages to st.session_state. and it solved the problem.